# Find variables from a multiplication of geometric sequences

Tags: combinatorics, geometric-series

> Given $$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i$$
> And $$f(x)(1+2x+2x^2+x^3) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^3}$$
> Find the values of $a_0$, $a_1$, and $a_2$.

I try to expand them but it doesn't seem to lead me to any solution.
How can I isolate a0, a1, and a2 to find them?

Answer (score 2):

Tip:

Notice $1+2x+2x^2+x^3=\left(1+x+x^2\right)(1+x)$

Then $$\begin{split}f(x)&=\frac1{(1-x)^3(1+x)\left(1+x+x^2\right)}\\&=\frac1{1-x}\cdot\frac1{(1-x)(1+x)}\cdot\frac1{(1-x)\left(1+x+x^2\right)}\\&=\frac1{1-x}\cdot\frac1{1-x^2}\cdot\frac1{1-x^3}\\&=\left(1+x+x^2+x^3+...\right)\left(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+...\right)\left(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+...\right)\end{split}$$

Then expansion finishes it all. Try it!

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)= a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+O(x^3)$
$f(x)(1+2x+2x^2+x^3)$
$=a_0+(2a_0+a_1)x+(2a_0+2a_1+a_2) x^2
+O(x^3)$
$$\textrm{Again } f(x)(1+2x+2x^2+x^3)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=1+3x+6x^2+O(x^3)$$
Comparing the like powers of x we get:$$a_0=1,a_1=1,a_2=2$$

Comment: Can you please share an explanation about O function and what O(x^3) equals to?

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)(1+2x+2x^2+x^3) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^3}\implies $$ $$(1-x-x^2+x^4+x^5-x^6)\,f(x)=1$$

Now, let $f(x)=a+b x+c x^2$ and ignore the terms $x^n$ if $n>3$. This gives
$$a+ (b-a)x- (a+b-c)x^2=1$$
Comparing the terms, $a=1$, $b=a=1$, $c=a+b=2$.

Comment: 1. Why f(x)=a+bx+cx2? ---------- 2. Why "ignore the terms xn if n>3"? ---------- 3. How you got to this "a+(b−a)x−(a+b−c)x2=1"?

Comment: @igalleikin. You want the first two terms; so why to care about $x^3$ ? The rest in multiplication and grouping terms of sam power.

Answer (score 1):

From the second condition we get
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^3(1+2x+2x^2+x^3)} \tag 1$$
From the first condition we get
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i = a_0 + a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3 + ... \tag 2$$
Hence, $$a_0 = f(0) \overset {(1)}= \dfrac{1}{1\cdot 1} = 1 \tag 3$$
To find $a_1$, differentiate $(2)$
$$f'(x) = a_1 + a_2x + ...$$ Hence, $$a_1 = f'(0)$$ wich you can find from $(1)$
$$f'(x)=-\frac{-3(1-x)^2(1+2x+2x^2+x^3) + (1-x)^3(2+4x+3x^2)}{\text{denominator}^2}$$ which gives $$ a_1 = f'(0) = -\frac{-3+2}{1} = 1$$
Similarly, you can find  $$a_2 = f''(0)$$

Comment: I don't think that is the best way to solve the problem. Double differentiating is not going to be that easy

Comment: @Forester Yes, but you don't need to differentiate and simplify till the end. We just need a "rough" form to plug $0$ in.

Comment: You are right but have a look at Culver's answer. That method is much simpler according to me. You can ignore the $(1+x^3+x^6+...)$  as well.

Comment: @Forester Yes, I didn't disagree when you said it was not the best way for this problem. Yet, also note that differentiating is a more general way to isolate the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Also possible as:
[image]

Thanks for all of your help guys! :)